# how to know 'each' done or re done in meteor blaze template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

`each` running after `onRendered` and `Tracker.autorun`(if `foo` is binding subscription data context).

so i can`t catch that`each` work is when done.

how to know `each` is work done, or rework and done?

is it unknown?

Below is an example.

```
<template name="something">
  {{#each foo}}
    <bar>bar</bar>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't see a real use case for this** but you can use a helper here that does not add anything to the render output:

```js
<template name="something">
  {{#each foo}}
    <bar>bar</bar>
    {{isDone @index foo}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.something.helpers({
  isDone(index, arr) {
    if (index === arr.length - 1) {
      // this was the last element
      // to be rendered. do whatever
      // you want here
    }
  }
})
```

Not that this is not really a best practice and **you should think about why you need to know this**? If you have performance issues with your rendering you want review your whole template code design and refactor where necessary.

Comment: Good performance can not be guaranteed, but it was a new attempt for me. Thanks for the answer. :)